# No scrollbar for R formattable

Tags: r, plot, formattable

I have a large dataframe that I presented as a `formattable` object. When the object renders in the R Studio viewer, I have a scrollbar to move up and down. But when I export the image it does not export the whole table, just a part of it. How can I export the whole table as an image?

Here is my code for the formattable object:

```
formattable(por.pais,align =c("c","c","c","c"),
        list('Equipo' = formatter("span", style = ~ style(color = "grey",font.weight ="bold")), 'Eficiencia'= color_tile(customRed, customGreen)))
```

And here is how R is exporting the image:
[formattable object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwtD2.png)

Comment: How exactly are you "exporting the image"?

Comment: using the "export" option from the Viewer in R Studio

Comment: i don't think the rstudio image exporter was designed for that, it could work but unsure what you would search for. An alternative is to open it in your browser and use any way to take a full page screenshot, like [GoFullPage](https://gofullpage.com/) for chrome/brave/etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found this code and it works to perfection:

First, install the formattable, htmltools and webshot packages:

```
install.packages("htmltools")
install.packages("webshot")
install.packages("formattable")
```

Now load them:

```
#Load the following libraries:
library("htmltools")
library("webshot")
```

Run the following function:

```
export_formattable <- function(f, file, width = "100%", height = NULL, 
                               background = "white", delay = 0.2)
{
  w <- as.htmlwidget(f, width = width, height = height)
  path <- html_print(w, background = background, viewer = NULL)
  url <- paste0("file:///", gsub("\\\\", "/", normalizePath(path)))
  webshot(url,
          file = file,
          selector = ".formattable_widget",
          delay = delay)
}
```

Now, create a formattable object:

```
tb <- formattable(dataframe)
```

Fianlly, save your table as an image:

```
export_formattable(tb,"my_table.png")
```

Note: You can also use the .jpg extension.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in Viewer, Export, you can get a maximum of 1820 pixels wide and 796 pixels high. If you increase the pixels and click update preview this will help with medium sized tables that are within this size, but does not help if your table is bigger (like mine).

Comment: Did you manage to save it. I discovered how to save them. Could post the code for you.

Comment: I did not manage to save it, would be great to get the code. I had tried the below, but, as you said, it just produced an empty file. 

png(paste0(exportFolder, "Filename.png"), width = 2600, height = 1000,
    res = 300)
[createfile]
dev.off()

Comment: Sorry for taking so long, check my answer. It should work just fine. @ChrisD